# How to redirect with react-router and send a message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm looking for a way in React to redirect after a successful login with success message. After the login, another component should show a success message, so how do I inform it that the redirect was after successful login? I once did that with flash messages, but that solution did not use react-router and had full page refreshes.

I am now using react-router, and am curious whether there is a react-router way to pass state/message to another route when redirecting? I am redirecting with:

`browserHistory.push('/')`

so I've tried:

```
browserHistory.push({
    pathname: '/',
    state: {
        message: "my message"
    }
});
```

But target component's `this.state` remained null. Is there a way to achieve what I want using react-router's own API? Or maybe I'm trying to solve this problem incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found an answer myself, the method I tried does indeed work, but the pushed state is received from:

`this.props.location.state`

in target component.